# How to import :bigdec data into datomic

Tags: schema, datomic

I have this schema:

```
[
  {:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db]
   :db/ident :atr/amount
   :db/valueType :db.type/bigdec
   :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
   :db/fulltext false
   :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}

  {:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db]
   :db/ident :atr/clientId
   :db/valueType :db.type/string
   :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
   :db/fulltext true
   :db/doc "The client who owns this atr"
   :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}

  {:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db]
   :db/ident :atr/currency
   :db/valueType :db.type/string
   :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
   :db/fulltext true
   :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}

  {:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db]
   :db/ident :atr/valueDate
   :db/valueType :db.type/instant
   :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
   :db/fulltext true
   :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}

  {:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db]
   :db/ident :community/reference
   :db/valueType :db.type/string
   :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
   :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}
]
```

I try to insert this data:

```
[
    {:db/id 1, :atr/amount 10, :atr/currency "USD", :atr/clientId "clientId", :atr/valueDate "2014-02-14"}
]
```

I get this error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: :db.error/wrong-type-for-attribute Value 10 is not a valid :bigdec for attribute :atr/amount
```

How do I describe bigdec data for import into datomic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the appropriate data literal to express the value in this case (using M to indicate BigDecimal):

```
(def foo-tx
  [
    {:db/id (d/tempid :db.part/user)
     :atr/amount 10M
     :atr/currency "USD"
     :atr/clientId "clientId"
     :atr/valueDate #inst "1985-04-12T23:20:50.52Z"} ;;)(new java.util.Date)}
   ])
```

Or otherwise create the correct value type (as with date below):

```
(def foo-tx
  [
    {:db/id (d/tempid :db.part/user)
     :atr/amount 10M
     :atr/currency "USD"
     :atr/clientId "clientId"
     :atr/valueDate (new java.util.Date)}
   ])
```

Both of these examples will transact correctly against your schema.